# are mysqli functions the same as mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a website that I made pretty recently only to learn that MySQL is deprecated.  Problem is, I have 321 occurrences of mysql statements in the entirety of my website, and I'm hoping that there is an easy way to convert to mysqli (or PDO).  Would a simple find and replace of mysql with myqsli do it?

Below are the only mysql functions I use, though connect and select_db I use only once in a connect file and use the require function for each connection.

- `mysql_connect`
- `mysql_select_db`
- `mysql_query`
- `mysql_num_rows`
- `mysql_fetch_assoc`
- `mysql_close`

I've seen other people asking similar questions, but with very specific examples.  I'm asking if I do a find and replace if it's going to cause any problems

Comment: It is not a straight up replacement except in a few circumstances. You're better off changing out each page and testing as you go. Many people choose to isolate similar functions in such a way as to make them reusable in a function call or something similar. There are a lot of helpful hints [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi).

Comment: *"Would a simple find and replace of mysql with myqsli do it?"* - No. MySQLi requires DB connection be passed to all functions. You could do a search and replace to a certain extent, but not for the connection parameter.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Is there anything specific you might warn me of based on the functions I use?  I knew this would be down voted by those users with nothing better to do, so I'm taking the hit to get this info.

Comment: Personally I think PDO is better than MySQLi.  Its more generic so if you ever end up using a different DB than just MySQL it would be good to know. And since `mysqli_` is not a direct translation from `mysql_` you might as well go all the way to PDO.

Comment: You're welcome. If you're going to switch over, then I suggest you use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*. Start off fresh.

Comment: "Many people choose to isolate similar functions in such a way as to make them reusable in a function call or something similar." This from @JayBlanchard. You should not have to fix 321 places in your code to fix this problem, these should be re-usable functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the switch to mysqli in about 5 minutes.  I connect using `require("connect.php")`

connect.php use to be

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host", "usename", "password");
mysql_select_db("DataBaseName")
?>
```

which I changed to

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("host", "usename", "password","DataBaseName");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

All occurrences of mysql_num_rows and mysql_fetch_assoc were replaced with mysqli_num_rows and mysqli_fetch_assoc respectively.

All occurrences of "mysql_query(" were replaced with "mysqli_query($connection" (without the quotes, of course).

All occurences of mysql_close() were replaced with mysqli_close($connection)

It all seems to work.  Perhaps not the best or most secure method, but it did save me from having to replace 321 lines!  Thanks to all for your help.